# Saving the XML document, breaks my XSI declaration

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have a question:

I am parsing an XML that has a namespace with a python xml parser ( [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) ), and when I save that xml the parser replaces: "xsi:" in the namespace with {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance} how can I prevent him from doing that ?

Example:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
```

Becomes:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
```

Can anyone help me out with this  ?

Regards,
Bojan

Comment: Sounds like a bug in BS.

Comment: I know, I was just trying to figure out if anyone knows how to get around that bug, because I couldn't find a quick way of fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [filed a bug for you.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1037597) I've also committed a fix which will be in the next release of Beautiful Soup.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I temporarily solved it.

```
soupOut = str(soup)
ns = re.search("<project [^>]* xmlns:xsi=\"(?P<ns>[^\"]*)\"[^>]*>",soupOut)
if ns:
    soupOut = soupOut.replace("{%s}"%ns.group('ns'), 'xsi:')
file.write(soupOut)
```